# ChartJS '_meta' error for AJAX Dataset

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using Chart.js Bundle and Jquery

```
var toll;
        $.ajax({
            async   : false,
            type    : "GET",
            url : "barChartData.php",
            success : function(data) {
                toll = data;
            }
        });

        var barChartData = {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July','August','September','October','Novemeber','December'],
            datasets: [
                toll
            ]

        };
```

Above code is giving following error: TypeError: Cannot create property '_meta' on string '

Comment: hi.. did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

`success` is a callback function, meaning that it executes only after the ajax call is complete. This means that the variable `barChartData` is getting initialised before `toll` has any values. In fact, `toll` has not been initialised, since you've simply written `var toll;`.

1. Initialize `toll`, and set it to null value.
2. Get access to your chart.
3. Add the toll data to your datasets and update the chart *inside* the success function.

   ```
   var toll = null;
   var chart = ... //Hopefully you have access to the instance of your chart? If not, please show the rest of your code.
   $.ajax({
       async   : false,
       type    : "GET",
       url : "barChartData.php",
       success : function(data) {
           toll = data;
           barChartData.datasets.push(toll);
           chart.update();
       }
   });

   var barChartData = {
       labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July','August','September','October','Novemeber','December'],
       datasets: []
   };
   ```